# Refresh repositories in solaris 10

Tags: solaris, repository

Is there a way to refresh the repositories in solaris 10, similar to `apt update`?

Comment: My recollection is that Solaris 10 doesn't have repositories containing various versions of packages; it has collections of packages, and separate collections (available only to support contract holders) of patches to update those packages. So maybe `updatemanager` or `smpatch` will do what you're looking to do.

Comment: Mark is correct. Luis you are confusing with Solaris 11 which really has software repos. (Solaris 11 came out 5 years ago and is VASTLY superior to Solaris 10 in so many ways - software package mgmt being one of them. You really should consider upgrading)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Solaris 10 there are no repositories. You do have patch bundles (available under support contracts) that include all the patches. Alternativaly you might use `smpatch`. Software packages are provided as standalone and might have dependencies. Unfortunately with Solaris 10 package manager  you need to solve these dependencies manually.

With Solaris 11 you have repositories and can create your own as well. It enables you to publish your own packages and solves the dependencies automatically. Similar to Solaris 10, updates to the base image are available only via a support contract. [IPS](https://www.google.pl/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi0p92kifDNAhXjCpoKHfnqAsUQFggbMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.oracle.com%2Ftechnetwork%2Farticles%2Fservers-storage-admin%2Fo11-083-ips-basics-523756.html&usg=AFQjCNGxS8eVXjdBJXrGBMoba1Us_gjP7w&bvm=bv.126993452,d.bGs)

If you are asking how do refresh the package repositories in Solaris 11 you can do:

> pkg refresh

to update the local repository follow this [link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/E21803/updaterepo.html)